# Как из sql-базы выдернуть нужные данные по дате с помощью python

Tags: python, sql, asterisk

В программирование только начинаю, споткнулся об один момент.
От предшественника остался скрипт на питоне, который дергает из базы данные по определенной строке и записывает результат в нужный файл.
Было для теста:

```
def main():
mysqlConn = getMysqlConn()
try:
    with mysqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT phone FROM workersSchedule WHERE month=%s and day=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (11,18))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        phone = result['phone']
        file = open('/etc/asterisk/scripts/workerPhone.txt', 'w')
        if phone == '' or phone is None:
            phone = 'тут был номер'
        file.write(phone)
        file.close()
finally:
    mysqlConn.close()
```

Но в этом случае дергались данные из строки по совпадению cursor.execute(sql, (11,18)). То есть, month=11 и day=18.

Требуется сделать так, чтоб из столбцов month и day сравнивал с текущим днем.
Попробовал подобный вариант, но не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

```
def main():
mysqlConn = getMysqlConn()
try:
    with mysqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT `phone` FROM `workersSchedule` WHERE `month`=%s and `day`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')), int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d')))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        phone = result['phone']
        file = open('/etc/asterisk/scripts/workerPhone.txt', 'w')
        if phone == '' or phone is None:
            phone = 'тут был номер'
        file.write(phone)
        file.close()
finally:
    mysqlConn.close()
```

Comment: что значит "не работает"? тест ошибки? у вашего предшественника параметры в cursor.execute() передаются кортежем. Может, и вам стоит так же сделать?

Comment: При использовании такого способа, как во втором примере, выдает ошибку:
на строку cursor.execute(sql, int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')), int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))). Идет ошибка  TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Как это все кортежем сделать - не знаю. Т.к. нужно будет выбирать данные по столбцам, исходя из совпадений сегодняшней даты.

Comment: Во-первых `cursor.execute(sql, (int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')), int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))))` - видите месяц и день в скобки обернул как в изначальном примере? Во-вторых не нужно дату месяц и день в строку преобразовывать, потом обратно целые числа превращать, их можно напрямую как числа получить: `(datetime.datetime.now().month, datetime.datetime.now().day)`

Comment: @insolor Огромное спасибо, помогла ваша правка, просто тупейшая ошибка. Преобразование такое пока оставлю, чуть разберусь во всем и сделаю как нужно.

Comment: Ок, я добавлю ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В оригинале в excute передаются два параметра - sql запрос и кортеж (tuple) с параметрами запроса:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (11,18))
```

В вашем коде вы передаете три параметра - sql запрос, месяц, день:

```
cursor.execute(sql, int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')), int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d')))
```

Параметры запроса (месяц и день) нужно передавать в виде tuple (обернуть в скобки, по сути):

```
cursor.execute(sql, (int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')), int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))))
```

Также для получения месяца и дня в виде чисел не нужно сначала их получать в виде строки, и потом преобразовывать в числа, достаточно напрямую обратиться к полям month и day:

```
(datetime.datetime.now().month, datetime.datetime.now().day)
```

Для лучшей читаемости текущую дату-время лучше получить один раз, записать в переменную, а потом уже из нее получать нужные поля (вообще хорошая идея - не пытаться все уместить в одну строку):

```
sql = "SELECT phone FROM workersSchedule WHERE month=%s and day=%s"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
cursor.execute(sql, (now.month, now.day))
```